# Mysql Replication stops without error

Tags: mysql, replication

Mysql 5.1 Replication stops without error message

```
"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G"
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
>                   Master_Host: xxx
>                   Master_User: repl
>                   Master_Port: 3306
>                 Connect_Retry: 60
>               Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000366
>           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 6491726
>                Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000003
>                 Relay_Log_Pos: 75183691
>         Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000351
>              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
>             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
>               Replicate_Do_DB: xxx
>           Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
>            Replicate_Do_Table: 
>        Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
>       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:    
>   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
>                    Last_Errno: 0
>                    Last_Error: 
>                  Skip_Counter: 0
>           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 75698643
>               Relay_Log_Space: 1624786550
>               Until_Condition: None
>                Until_Log_File: 
>                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
>            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
>            Master_SSL_CA_File: 
>            Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
>               Master_SSL_Cert: 
>             Master_SSL_Cipher: 
>                Master_SSL_Key: 
>         Seconds_Behind_Master: 6222 
> Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
>                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
>                 Last_IO_Error: 
>                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
>                Last_SQL_Error:
```

Last binlog on master is mysql-bin.000365

What should I do and read to solve this trouble?

Comment: Both `Slave_IO_Running: Yes` and `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes` so what makes you think replication is not running?

Comment: you have to re-configure your slave and re-load data from master, as the log-bin is different between slave and master, it probably **NOT** able to catch up with master anymore

Comment: Seconds_Behind_Master: 6222 value was bigger - 52 hour from master and Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000351 is not last binlog/ Last is 000666.

Comment: we did reconfigure several times but every time occurs the same problem. Slave stops at 000351 binlog.

Comment: I am getting the same silent replication failure. In my case, slave status shows seconds_behind_master: 0

Comment: sorry, maybe have anybody figured out cause of the problem?

Comment: You can check solving problem Master-Slave in mysql [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838040/mysql-error-1236-from-master-when-reading-data-from-binary-log?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-configure MySQL Slave because your slave is showing `Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000366` however you are saying that your Master is at `mysql-bin.000365`. That's why your slave is unable to sync from Master. To re-configure Slave follow these setps [here](http://www.techguy-mw.com/mysql-replication/)